# Using functions while overloading an operator

Tags: c++, printing, operator-overloading, cout, ostream

I'm currently working on a game to brush up my C++ skills and I'm trying to use more advanced concepts in order to learn more about the language itself.

I'm creating a deck of cards using an `enum` to store the values and would like to overload the `<<` operator to have a clean way to print everything.

```
//Card.h
private:
    Value value;
    Suit suit;

enum Value {
        TWO = 2, THREE...
    };
enum Suit {
        DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS, HEARTS
    };
Card(Value value, Suit suit);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Card& card);
```

In order to maintain readability, I have `get` functions for values and suits using switch/case.

```
std::string Card::getSuit() {
    int c = suit;
    std::string strSuit;
    switch(c) {
        case 0:
            strSuit = "Diamonds";
            break;
        case 1:
            strSuit = "Spades";
            break;
        case 2:
            strSuit = "Clubs";
            break;
        case 3:
            strSuit = "Hearts";
            break;
        default:
            ;
    }
    return strSuit;
}
```

(`getValue` is similar but omitted to reduce question length)

My idea for the function to overload the operator is:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Card& card) {
    std::string v = card.getValue();
    std::string s = card.getSuit();
    output << v << " of " << s << std::endl;
    return output;
}
```

however the `get` functions do not work because of a conflict with the `const` (which I do not fully understand).

How can I overload this operator cleanly, without having to duplicate the switch/case statements?

Comment: So... why aren't `getSuit()` and `getValue()` const ? It's not like either one has any need/reason to modify the host object.

Comment: When changing the function declaration to `const std::string Card::getValue()` I get the warning `Return type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char>') is 'const'-qualified at the top level, which may reduce code readability without improving const correctness` and the compiler says `'this' argument to member function 'getValue' has type 'const Card', but function is not marked const` even though the function is marked `const` in the header file too.

Comment: Both the member decl in the class def *and* the member implementation (if it is outside of the class def) must match `const`ness. You're adding const in the wrong place. It should be after the closing `)` of the argument list, before the `;` in the decl, or before the opening `{` in the implementation. E.g. `std::string getValue() const;` in the member decl, and `std::string Card::getValue() const { .... }` in the implementation.

Comment: Amazing, that worked. I was placing `const` before the data type of the function. I didn't know it should go after the argument list, that's new to me. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

'const' on the C++ member function basically means that it's 'read-only',the function is not allowed to alter/modify any member variables of the class-instance (this) - and to to call other functions, those must also be 'const', example, this would be illegal, and not compile:

```
int SomeClass::getSomeValue() const
{
    this->some_example_counter++; // not allowed to modify member here
    return this->some_member_value;
}
```

Now it's possible to define 'some_example_counter' as 'mutable', and then it will be allowed to be modified/altered from a 'const' member function.

```
class SomeClass {
   ...
   mutable int some_example_counter;
}
```

There are some few rare use-cases where 'mutable' will make sense, like for example when a 'mutex' may be needed, otherwise personally I avoid using 'mutable'.

In your code:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Card& card)
```

The second parameter 'const Card& card' - you can only call memeber function of Card class that are 'const' *(read-only)*
I think it would in any case make sense to have both Card::getValue() and Card::getSuit() as 'const' - as they naturally don't alter/modify any member variable of Card.